# Slow response via TCP for Azure Linux VM

Tags: mysql, linux, azure, virtual-machine

I created a linux virtual machine with mysql for development tests, and sometimes a simple query take so much time to return a response on tcp connection, but the same query running local returns in 0.00 secs.

I think the reason for a long time sometimes is because the application is trying to open a connection (and maybe this is slow), after connection the response time is small for next queries.

Maybe the problem is on azure vnet, but I don't know.

What Can I do to reduce this response time?

Comment: If you are trying to get to mundocompilado.com - when I try to get there from Google Chrome, I get an error message Error 522 indicating I traveled through Atlanta Cloudflare but then I am getting mundocompilado.com Error 522 connection timed out with Host Error on the lower right side of the page - rather than connecting.  If your effort is to another URL, that would be a different problem.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: As I said, in localhost the queries run in 0 seconds, very fast. But when I run from a remote application, like MySQL workbench, sometimes I see for some seconds the message "running query", and this is the problem, from remote. The VM is a azure B2s.

Comment: Is your application at www.mundocompilado.com?  There is something between us and your local host getting in the way.  We need to determine the probable cause.  The additional information requested will go a long way towards determining road blocks.

Comment: This vm hasn't any relationship with mundocompilado.com. And I don't know what more detail I can share here to help with the solution. It just what I said before, it is a simple B2s vm with a MySQL on Port 3306, just it.

Comment: Additional information request. Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? Post on pastebin.com and share the links. From your SSH login root, Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue. I've tried connecting with App Services and with a VM. Both experience 10s+ delays receiving a response from the Azure for MySQL database.